# Error While Saving Product and doing reindex in Magento2.3

Tags: magento2, product, reindex, save

When I run the reindexing command got this error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\InventoryIndexer\Model\StockIndexTableNameResolverInterface in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116 Stack trace: #0 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Invento...', Array) #1 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(150): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Invento...')
#2 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(79): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->get('Magento\\Invento...')
#3 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Invento...')
#4 /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/In in /home/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116
```

Got the same error when saving product.

Comment: can we see your di.xml please ?

Comment: I think issue is with core magento indexing, he didn't add any new di.xml file

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/149735)

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same issue when trying to reindex and after investigating, I realized that some of Magento's modules starting with "*Magento_Inventory*" were activated and some others were not.

When we upgraded our project to 2.3 we had to deactivate all of those modules so that our "normal" inventories would still work as expected, since we are not going to use the 2.3 multi inventories feature. Although, it seems that by some mistake a few of those modules were reactivated in our config.php file - leading to an interface being declared without any dependency injected.

I suggest that you check your config file to see if those modules are activated or not, as I believe they should be altogether activated or deactivated instead of having some and other not.

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands

```
php bin/magento c:c
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -dmemory_limit=1G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

This should resolve your issue